# control iframe src page is divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

is there any way i could control divs on pages that is in iframe src using php or javascript?

for example on my page i have iframe and when page loaded and there must be a button when i clicked on it, it will remove the div that is on page on iframe src

hope you understand what i mean guys. here is an example http://plnkr.co/edit/243NWElmuWhM1B3g8Zyq?p=preview

here's my page codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <iframe style="border:1px solid #444;" src="http://tgo-tv.com/box-test.php" frameborder="0"  scrolling="no" width="100" height="100"></iframe>

    <div id="button">click to Remove red box only</div>

    <br>

    when that iframe src was loaded completely, then some how with javascript or php it must remove that red box is code inside it. i know it is on another page but maybe there is a way to do that

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the page which is on iframe on the same domain you use you can access the box element as any other element in the page
example to what you want to do:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $("#iframeID").contents().find("#box").css('display', 'none');
    // or if you want to remove it
    $("#iframeID").contents().find("#box").remove();
});
```

but if it isn't on the same domain so you will face cross origin problem, and i don't think it will be possible to access an element inside it